# Integration of ruby on rails with AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js, npm-install

I am trying to create a Ruby On rails application with AngularJS. I already tried this by following [how to wire up ROR with angularJS Article](https://www.angularonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-single-page-application/) with mySQL database , But could not able to get any benefit. As i am new to AngularJS integration with ROR I faced following terminal command problems while trying above mentioned Link, and the problems are like:

- First problem in while I am trying `rails g rspec:install`
- Second problem is due to `npm install -g yo` command and then
- third is `npm install -g generator-angular`
  Please help me by sending another Article , So that i can go ahead with this. 
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem 'angularjs-rails' for integration of rails app with angularjs.

Comment: okay, thanks again @AmitAttri. I found one more article by searching 'angularjs-rails' and that is useful. Here is the link of (https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2014/07/17/building-web-apps-with-rails4-and-angularjs-in-15-minutes/) Article